# Split text file basing on date tag / timestamp

Tags: bash, debian

I have big log file containing date tags. It looks like this:

```
[01/11/2015, 02:19]
foo
[01/11/2015, 08:40]
bar
[04/11/2015, 12:21]
foo
bar
[08/11/2015, 14:12]
bar
foo
[09/11/2015, 11:25]
...
[15/11/2015, 19:22]
...
[15/11/2015, 21:55]
...
```

and so on. I need to split these data into files of days, like:

01.txt:

```
[01/11/2015, 02:19]
foo
[01/11/2015, 08:40]
bar
```

04.txt:

```
[04/11/2015, 12:21]
foo
bar
```

etc. How can I do that using any of unix tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a tool that will do it without a little programming, but with Awk the little programming really isn't all that hard.

#### `script.awk`

```
/^\[[0-3][0-9]\/[01][0-9]\/[12][0-9]{3},/ {
    if ($1 != old_date)
    {
        if (outfile != "") close(outfile);
        outfile = sprintf("%.2d.txt", ++filenum); 
        old_date = $1
    }
}
{ print > outfile }
```

The first (bigger) block of code recognizes the date string, which is also in `$1` (so the condition could be made more precise by referring to `$1`, but the benefit it minimal to non-existent).  Inside the actions, it checks to see if the date is different from the last date it remembered.  If so, it checks whether it has a file open and closes it if necessary (`close` is part of POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)).  Then it generates a new file name, and remembers the current date it is processing.

The second smaller block simply writes the current line to the current file.

#### Invocation

```
awk -f script.awk data
```

This assumes you have a file `script.awk`; you could provide it as a script argument if you prefer.  If the whole is encapsulated in a shell script, I'd use an expression rather than a second file, but I find it convenient for development to use a file.  (The shell script would contain `awk '…the script…' "$@"` with no separate file.)

#### Example output files

Given the sample data from the question, the output is in five files, `01.txt` .. `05.txt`.

```
$ for file in 0?.txt; do boxecho $file; cat $file; done
************
** 01.txt **
************
[01/11/2015, 02:19]
foo
[01/11/2015, 08:40]
bar
************
** 02.txt **
************
[04/11/2015, 12:21]
foo
bar
************
** 03.txt **
************
[08/11/2015, 14:12]
bar
foo
************
** 04.txt **
************
[09/11/2015, 11:25]
...
************
** 05.txt **
************
[15/11/2015, 19:22]
...
[15/11/2015, 21:55]
...
$
```

The `boxecho` command is a simple script that echoes its arguments in a box of stars:

```
echo "** $* **" | sed -e h -e s/./*/g -e p -e x -e p -e x
```

#### Revised file name format

> I wish have output as a `[day].txt` or `[day].[month].[year].txt`, based on date in file. Is that possible?

Yes; it is possible and not particularly hard.  The `split` function is one way of dealing with breaking up the value in `$1`.  The regex specifies that square brackets, slashes and commas are the field separators.  There are 5 sub-fields in the value in `$1`: an empty field before the `[`, the three numeric components separated by slashes and an empty field after the `,`.  The array name, `dmy`, is mnemonic for the sequence in which the components are stored.

```
/^\[[0-3][0-9]\/[01][0-9]\/[12][0-9]{3},/ {
    if ($1 != old_date)
    {
        if (outfile != "") close(outfile)
        n = split($1, dmy, "[/\[,]")
        outfile = sprintf("%s.%s.%s.txt", dmy[4], dmy[3], dmy[2])
        old_date = $1
    }
}
{ print > outfile }
```

Permute the numbers 4, 3, 2 in the `sprintf()` statement to suit yourself.  The given order is year, month, day, which has many merits including that it is exploiting the ISO 8601 standard and the files sort automatically into date order. I strongly counsel its use, but you may do as you wish.  For the sample data and the input shown in the question, the files it generates are:

```
2015.11.01.txt
2015.11.04.txt
2015.11.08.txt
2015.11.09.txt
2015.11.15.txt
```

Comment: Cool, that's a nice work. But I wish have output as a `[day].txt` or `[day].[month].[year].txt`, based on date in file. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Which format do you want?  I note that the files will automatically appear in date order if you use the format `[year].[month].[day].txt`.  And I assume that the square brackets are not intended as a part of the file name on disk.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Perfect work. I'm impressed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea. I use `sed` command and awk script.

```
$ cat biglog
[01/11/2015, 02:19]
foo
[01/11/2015, 08:40]
bar
[04/11/2015, 12:21]
foo
bar
aaa
bbb
[08/11/2015, 14:12]
bar
foo

$ cat sample.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS = "\n"
  RS = "\n\n"
}

{
  date = substr($1, 2, 2)
  filename = date ".txt"

  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
    print $i >> filename
  }
}
```

**How to use**

```
sed -e 's/^\(\[[0-9][0-9]\)/\n\1/' biglog | sed -e 1d | ./sample.awk
```

**Confirmation**

```
ls *.txt
01.txt  04.txt  08.txt

$ cat 01.txt
foo
bar

$ cat 04.txt
foo
bar
aaa
bbb

$ cat 08.txt
bar
foo
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work - messed up with files: https://i.imgur.com/52npeZN.png

Comment: Thanks your comment. I'll check again. Are the <character>.txt like a .txt, aa.txt made by this script? I checked my script on CentOS6.7 gawk 3.1.7

Comment: Yes, all these files, excluding "2014.03.01 - (...)", were created by this script. Debian 8.

Answer (score 0):

yet another `awk`

```
$ awk -F"[[/,]" -v d="." '/^[\[0-9\/, :\]]*$/{f=$4 d $3 d $2 d"txt"} 
                                        {print $0>f}' file

$ ls 20*
2015.11.01.txt  2015.11.04.txt  2015.11.08.txt  2015.11.09.txt  2015.11.15.txt

$ cat 2015.11.01.txt 
[01/11/2015, 02:19]
foo
[01/11/2015, 08:40]
bar
```

Comment: Messed up even more. You have to know that there are a lot non-date tags text, like `[backspace]`, etc. - https://i.imgur.com/FqbJnG4.png (just a part)

Comment: Yes, I see... please see the update, I didn't anchor the pattern match.  now it will only match the time stamp line to set the file name correctly.

Comment: Also, if you're going to generate thousands of files, closing them might be a good idea.  For a few hundred files it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry. `Fatal error: expression for '>' redirection has zero value chain` (translated by Google Translate, as I'm in other language and honestly I have no idea how to translate it by myself)

Comment: Perhaps the sample input is not representative of your actual file? If you file starts not with a date/time stamp (where file name is declared) it might be the cause.